# Need help new to programming using Python and I am a little confused, its more like a really confused

Tags: python

Write a program that lets the user enter an integer N and then prints the sum of the first N odd integers. For example, if the user entered 4, it should print The sum of the first 4 odd numbers is 16. (since 1+3+5+7 = 16) Note that the number the user entered appears as part of the output.[10 pts]

The code below is all I have for the problem.

```
n = int(input('Enter the Number of Odd Integers:'))
firstNum = 1

for i in range(n-2):
    temp = firstNum
    secondNum = temp + 2
    firstNum = secondNum

print('The Sum:', (secondNum))
```

I know that you are supposed to end with, The sum of the __ odd numbers is __.

so the first blank is the input and second is the sum, but I dont know how to put them in a sentence answer like that.

Comment: maybe try posting the code you have before you ask.

Comment: can you modify the question?. The code is not clear !!

Comment: Yup just modified it thank you!

Comment: I fixed the question so its only showing the one I dont have now, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use a `for` loop:

```
num = int(raw_input('How high do you want the diamond to be? ')) #To get input

for i in range(1, num+1): #For loop to loop through numbers
        print ' '*(num-i)+'* '*i #Print the indent first, and then the stars for the diamond
for i in range(1, num+1): #Second for loop for other half of diamond
    print ' '*(i)+'* '*(num-i) #Print the indent first, and then the stars for the diamond
```

This runs as:

```
bash-3.2$ python diamond.py
How high do you want the diamond to be? 5
    * 
   * * 
  * * * 
 * * * * 
* * * * * 
 * * * * 
  * * * 
   * * 
    * 

bash-3.2$ python diamond.py
How high do you want the diamond to be? 21
                    * 
                   * * 
                  * * * 
                 * * * * 
                * * * * * 
               * * * * * * 
              * * * * * * * 
             * * * * * * * * 
            * * * * * * * * * 
           * * * * * * * * * * 
          * * * * * * * * * * * 
         * * * * * * * * * * * * 
        * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
       * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
      * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
     * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
    * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
   * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
  * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
 * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
 * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
  * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
   * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
    * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
     * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
      * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
       * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
        * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
         * * * * * * * * * * * * 
          * * * * * * * * * * * 
           * * * * * * * * * * 
            * * * * * * * * * 
             * * * * * * * * 
              * * * * * * * 
               * * * * * * 
                * * * * * 
                 * * * * 
                  * * * 
                   * * 
                    * 

bash-3.2$ python diamond.py
How high do you want the diamond to be? 7
      * 
     * * 
    * * * 
   * * * * 
  * * * * * 
 * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * 
 * * * * * * 
  * * * * * 
   * * * * 
    * * * 
     * * 
      * 

bash-3.2$
```

Comment: Thank You so much for helping me do this, the only thing is it also asks me to do a reverse triangle going down on the other side of the first one so that it is a diamond

Comment: Ah, k all work on that

Comment: Im so sorry for asking this of you, but you have been so nice! Even if you dont do the second part Im happy that you took the time out of your night to help me with this!

Comment: @Patrick, fixed it :) can you accept/+1 this answer please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For the first problem, you aren't adding the odd numbers together, instead you are simply increasing the value of secondNum. Instead, you want to add them all together.

The cute version

```
>>> def f():
    n = int(input('Enter N: '))
    print(sum(range(1,2*n,2)))


>>> f()
Enter N: 4
16
>>> f()
Enter N: 3
9
```

Comment: Thank You so much for the help, the other thing the question asks is to put the input and sum in the end sentence, like "The sum of the first 4 odd numbers is 16."